# rails sample app: how to render a text form to the right of each user listed (one per row)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails:

I'd like the

<%= render 'shared/intro_form' %>

to render a form for every user row displayed by

<%= render @users %>

I know that I'll need to embed the former line in the latter somehow, perhaps with an "each...do" statement, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right syntax. Thanks!

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
    <li><%= render @users %></li>
    <li><%= render 'shared/intro_form' %></li>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

3.4.5 Rendering Collections

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/intro_form", :collection => @users %>
```

Comment: thanks! step in the right direction, as i'm seeing multiple forms rendered (one per row), but i no longer am seeing the user names listed. do i need to include another @users in the beginning of the line?

Comment: you'll probably just want a line to display them within your partial.  You will have access to a user with the variable name `intro_form` (it uses the same name as your partial, so you may want to consider renaming the partial to something like `user`)

Comment: nevermind i got it<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
 <%= @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
  <%= render 'shared/intro_form' %>
 <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>

Comment: oh, I understand now, you already have a partial named `users`, I didn't realize that you could call render like that, just passing in a collection and no other params

Comment: you might want to pass the user into your intro form, if so, you can use: `:locals => {:user => user}` or `:object => user`

Comment: could you give me more context for the :locals => {:user => user} or :object => user code ?

Comment: `<%= render 'shared/intro_form', :locals => {:user => user} %>`